# Reading a Meter using OpenCV

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I am trying to read values on my electricity meter LCD display using opencv, From my picture I am able to find meter using HoughCircles method, I am able to find LCD display on meter using contours, the lcd display isn't so clear so again I search for contours to extract digits from display. Now I am unable to read values on the display using tesseract or ssocr, how can i read the values on LCD display. I just started using opencv (Beginner), don't know the right way to go from here and if my approach is correct, would appreciate any help. Below is my code snippet and the meter images links are in comments.

```
def process_image(path, index):
    img = cv2.imread(path)
    img = cv2.resize(img,(0,0),fx=2.0,fy=2.0)
    height, width, depth = img.shape
    print("\n---------------------------------------------\n")
    print("In Process Image Path is %s height is %d Width is %d depth is %d" %(path, height, width, depth))

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blur = cv2.medianBlur(gray, 15)
    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(blur, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1.2,100)

    # ensure at least one circles is found, which is our meter
    if circles is not None:
        circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
        print("Meter Found")
        for i in circles[0]:
            CenterX = i[0]
            CenterY = i[1]
            Radius = i[2]
            circle_img = np.zeros((height, width), np.uint8)
            cv2.circle(circle_img, (CenterX, CenterY), Radius, 1, thickness=-1)
            masked_data = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=circle_img)
            output = masked_data.copy()
            cv2.circle(output, (i[0], i[1]), i[2], (0, 255, 0), 2)
            cv2.circle(output, (i[0], i[1]), 2, (0, 0, 255), 3)
            cv2.imwrite("output_" + str(index) + ".jpg", output)
            break

        gray = cv2.cvtColor(output, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(5,5),1)
        edged = cv2.Canny(blurred, 5,10,200)
        cnts = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST,
                                cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

        cnts = cnts[0] if imutils.is_cv2() else cnts[1]
        cnts = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)
        displayCnt = None
        contour_list = []

        # loop over the contours
        for c in cnts:
            # approximate the contour
            peri = 0.02 * cv2.arcLength(c, True)
            approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c,peri, True)
            # if the contour has four vertices, then we have found
            # the meter display
            if len(approx) == 4:
                contour_list.append(c)
                cv2.contourArea(c)
                displayCnt = approx
                break

        warped = four_point_transform(gray, displayCnt.reshape(4, 2))
        output = four_point_transform(output, displayCnt.reshape(4, 2))
        thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(warped, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 31, 2)

        cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        cnts = cnts[0] if imutils.is_cv2() else cnts[1]
        digitCnts = []

        # loop over the digit area candidates
        for c in cnts:
            # compute the bounding box of the contour
            (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
            # if the contour is sufficiently large, it must be a digit
            if (w > 5 and w < 100) and (h >= 15 and h <= 150) :
                digitCnts.append(c)

        # sort the contours from left-to-right, then initialize the
        # actual digits themselves
        digitCnts = contours.sort_contours(digitCnts,method="left-to-right")[0]

        mask = np.zeros(thresh.shape, np.uint8)
        cv2.drawContours(mask, digitCnts, -80, (255, 255, 255),-1)
        mask = cv2.bitwise_not(mask)
        mask = cv2.resize(mask, (0, 0), fx=2.0, fy=2.0)
        result = os.popen('/usr/local/bin/ssocr --number-digits=-1 -t 10 Mask.jpg')
        output = result.read()
        print("Output is " + output)
        output = output[2:8]
        return str(round(float(output) * 0.1, 1))
    else:
        print("Circle not Found")
        print("\n---------------------------------------------\n")
        return None
```

Comment: [Meter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWUeb.jpg)
[LCD Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCvO2.jpg)
[Extracted Digits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4eyD.jpg)

Comment: Looks like your input image is so bad that it will be almost impossible to get any useful output. What can you do to improve the input?